# Execute a function when Http Request finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, http, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequests to load large amounts of data from a Flask REST API for my Machine Learning project. Let's say I have the following (simplified) setup:

```
const urlData1 = 'someUrl';
const urlData2 = 'someUrl';

var data1Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data2Req = new XMLHttpRequest();

data1Req.addEventListener("load", data1Listener);
data2Req.addEventListener("load", data2Listener);

var data1Storage;
var data2Storage;

function data1Listener() {
    data1Storage = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}

function data2Listener() {
    data2Storage = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}

data1Req.open("GET", urlData1, true);
data1Req.send();

data2Req.open("GET", urlData2, true);
data2Req.send();

// How do I do something with both data1Storage and data2Storge once they are loaded?
```

The problem with this is that I can't know when both data has been stored to their respective variables (data1Storage and data2Storage). Since they are very large data, it takes quite a long time to load, and accessing them right away will return an undefined. How do I manipulate these two variables only when data has been stored in them? My first thought was to do an if statement like `if (data1Storage!= undefined && data2Storage != undefined)`, but that obviously does not work.

Comment: Your if statement should work, it's just you need to place it inside both data1Listener & data2Listener..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change your `data1Listener` & `data2Listener` functions in the following way:

```
async data1Listener() {
    try {
        data1Storage = await JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log('Finished putting into data1Storage');
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}

async data2Listener() {
    try {
        data2Storage = await JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log('Finished putting into data2Storage');
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

The `async` keyword in front of a function allows you to `await` inside of it.

The `await` keyword will, as its name suggests, wait for the completion of the current statement before moving onto the next line.

In these functions, the `await` appears before `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`.

Therefore, only once `this.responseText` has been fully parsed and contained by the `data1Storage` & `data2Storage` variables will the `console.log` lines execute.

If an error occurs at any time inside the `try` block, an error will be thrown by the `catch` block. (As an example, if `this.responseText` is invalid JSON and cannot be parsed, then the `console.log` will not run and an error instead will be printed.